# What does "<" mean in a MatLab classdef?

Tags: matlab

I have a line of code that looks like this:

```
classdef labJack < handle
```

I do not know what the symbol "<" does in the code or why it was used. Does anyone know what it means to use this line?

Comment: It is [used to specify a superclass](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/classdef-block.html#brqy3km-8). In this case, it subclasses `handle` allowing objects to be passed around by reference.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, it specifies inheritance. It is the equivalent of `extends` in Java.

In this particular case class `labJack` is derived from class `handle`, which is special. Objects of classes derived from `handle` are passed by reference, and their methods can modify the object.